# Checking for null vs using || when getting length

Tags: javascript

I have been working on a project and I often have to get the length of a variable. I recently started using the following syntax because I think it looks better and is faster to type, especially when I have long variable names and multiple conditions.

```
if ((myArrayVariable || "").length > 0) {
    // Do stuff...
}
```

Previously, I did it like this:

```
if (myArrayVariable != null && myArrayVariable.length > 0) {
    // Do stuff...
}
```

What I want to know is, if/(how much) the first syntax is less efficient?

Comment: Doing it that way is fine, I generally prefer `if (var && var.length) { ...` but performancewise you'll never notice any difference.

Comment: Yes one or the other might be a few microseconds faster. Definitely something to stay awake nights worrying about. Seriously do whatever is most readable and feels right and your approach is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To test the performance, I made a [jsperf test](http://jsperf.com/check-array-is-not-null-and-empty) that test null, an empty array, and an array with one element on the following variants:

- The first style `(array || '').length > 0`
- The second syntax `array != null && array.length > 0`
- The third version `array && array.length`

The initial run indicates that the first variation is **96% slower** than the others. Additionally the other two are nearly the same, though [adeneo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/965051/adeneo)'s [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29704219/#comment-47544244) is about half a percent faster than the second.

[image: The first is 96% slower than the others]

Comment: FWIW see http://jsperf.com/check-array-is-not-null-and-empty/2. I've removed the `> 0` from all test cases, added a try-catch variation (very slow), and changed the first style to `array || []`. The first version is then 80% slower than the second. The third version is 50% slower for some reason. However, unless this is being run millions of times in a tight loop, I'd go for what I consider to be the more readable first or third versions.

Comment: @torazaburo I tested the edit in Firefox and first is even slower, and the second and third are almost the same. The original tests used the OP's snippets, since that was specifically what the question asked. Normally I would have wrote it as you did.